# 599 error when running JDBC request in Jmeter through Maven

Tags: maven, jdbc, jmeter

When running Jmeter with JDBC request in Maven project, I am getting 599 error in report for JDBC requests. Not sure, why I am not able to run it. I tried adding dependencies in the POM.xml but still getting 599 status code for it. Could someone please help me on this.

Comment: Please add full error and jdbc configuration and jars

Comment: there are no errors in the logs, only thing that I am getting is 599 status code for JDBC request.
I am trying to connect to informix database., 
<dependencies>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>JDBCDrivers.Informix</groupId>  
      <artifactId>ifxjdbc</artifactId>  
      <version>1.0</version>
     </dependency>
    </dependencies>
Using the above line in pom.xml to get the Jars. I am getting message of downloading from the repo, but this looks to be proxy error. Not sure what 599 error exactly means in this case.

Comment: IBM Informix Messages and Corrections:  599 Cannot mix IBM Informix Dynamic Server syntax with 
        IBM Informix SE syntax.

Comment: What's your JDBC request?

Comment: it is normal select query.

Comment: I am using it for database assertion, where I am trying to validate the script with the data created by the script and comparing it with that from the DB. but DB is not getting connected through Maven it seems and it is giving me 599.